# for each unique column value, plot line plot with multiple hues on different columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, seaborn

My pandas dataframe is like this

```
name,id,score1,score2,score3
ax,1,32,43,32
sy,1,34,22,22
ax,2,22,6,8
ax,3,10,5,4
bz,1,22,2,2
sy,2,10,1,0
bz,2,9,8,1
```

How can I create a line plot in seaborn for each unique name where id would be the x-axis, and the y-axis would be value, and the hue would be 'score1', 'score2', and 'score3'? Each unique name will have a separate line plot.

```
sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers", hue="month")
```

I wonder how do u handle the scenario where the hue is on different columns on a pandas dataframe? In my case, that is 'score1', 'score2', score3'

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: what are year, passenger, and month? can you draw a schematic of what you expect?

Comment: The code `sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers", hue="month")` isn't related to my data, I was just giving an example @mozway

Comment: Then please provide a schematic of the graph you want, it's currently unclear

Comment: Thanks for advice, I missed the schematic @mozway

Comment: If you have a moment, please update the question with the schematic this will be useful to future readers (and I might update the answer if needed)

Comment: Updated my question to make it clearer, thanks for advice @mozway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is unclear, but you can always [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) your data before plotting:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data=df.melt(['name', 'id'], var_name='score', value_name='value'),
             x='id', y='value', style='name', hue='score')
```

Output:

[image]